# Is there a src.jar in OSX?

Tags: java, windows, macos

In Windows, there is ( was a )  `src.jar` file that contains the java source files of the Java platform.

Is there something similar for Java 1.6 in OSX? I would like to specify this to my IDE so I can navigate to that source.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java/Eclipse on MacOSX: where is the src.zip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011002/java-eclipse-on-macosx-where-is-the-src-zip)

Comment: The post you linked as duplicate was made ***after*** this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my system src.jar is in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home

Comment: +1 Mine, too. I see `src.jar` in all three installed homes under 10.5.8.

Comment: I mess something with my installation. I don't see "apppledocs.jar" "docs.jar" nor "src.jar"  but a manage to borrow somebody else's Mac and I see it there.

Comment: Found in the same location on Snow Leopard 10.6.3

Answer (score 7):

On Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion), you have to first download and install the developer package:

1. go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action
2. log in (or sign up for a developer account)
3. search for "**java**" in the search box above Categories
4. choose the newest **Java for Mac OS X 10.7 Update *XXX* Developer Package**
5. download and install

src.jar can then be found in:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_***.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar
```

---

On the older Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard), you do the same as above, except look for the newest **Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update *XXX* Developer Package**):

src.jar can then be found in:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_***.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar
```

Comment: Its best to go to the Java downloads section linked above and get the latest rev of the JDK sources (update 4 at the time of my comment).

Comment: anyone have any luck finding this for 10.7? I haven't

Comment: @Kirby mine is still in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_26-b03-383.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar, not sure if that is because I upgraded 10.6 -> 10.7

Comment: From what I can read if you have a fresh 10.7 install, not an upgrade, then the src.jar is not available. Additionally, when I was looking on the internets for it on Mar 8, Apple's developer site was (gasp) down.

Comment: Did work for me with "Java for OS X 2013-005 Developer Package"

Answer (score 2):

[According to this blog post](http://jimbarritt.com/non-random/2009/12/02/java-sources-src-jar-for-jdk-on-osx/) you may have to install them seperately.

Answer (score 0):

See [Java](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wo/8.1.17.2.1.3.3.1.0.1.1.0.3.10.3.3.1) on connect.apple.com for Mac OS X 10.7 .

Answer (score -2):

The website http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/README.html discusses the source code. The JDK which contains src.jar can be downloaded from http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp

Comment: Sun's Java isn't exactly Apple's.