# Java/Eclipse on MacOSX: where is the src.zip?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

With the latest Java update on MacOSX 10.6, Eclipse does not find the Java sources anymore.

I am not exactly sure (i.e. don't remember anymore) if I have downloaded the sources manually in the past and put them somewhere or if MacOSX provided them and Eclipse found them automatically.

Does MacOSX have the sources somewhere? (Please no assumptions here. I really want to know that.)

If not, where can I get them?

Comment: did you install the jdk or the jre? the jdk has the source code as far as I can tell but not the jre on it's own

Comment: @hhafez: I have not installed anything. It is preinstalled by MacOSX. But it must be the JDK because I am able to compile things.

Comment: The hack-of-least-resistance on my snow leopard macbook was to change the default JRE from "Java SE 6 (MacOS X Default)" to just "Java SE 6".  "Java SE 6" has its location at /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_29-b11-402.jdk/Contents/Home which has a src.jar.  "Java SE 6 (MacOS X Default)" has its location at /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home which does not have src.jar.  I am hopeful that software updates to Java 6 keeps this fresh.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After installing the most recent Java update you'll find src.jar under

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_22-b04-307.jdk/Contents/Home

That's where I pointed "JRE home" for Java 1.6 in Eclipse to. Everything works as expected (until now :)

Comment: What... :P Have I really always overlooked this? I think I always have looked at the JDK which is installed in `/System/Library/...`. I didn't knew there was also *another* JDK in `/Library/...`.

Comment: I don't have /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines - I think that must be something Sebastian put in himself.

Comment: @Mike Baranczak: You should have `/Library/Java/Home/src.jar`. The newer one in `JavaVirtualMachines` is a developer release.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I added some related NetBeans findings in an adjacent answer.

Comment: I don't have `/Library/Java/Home/src.jar` _or_ `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.*`. I have `/Syste,/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home`, but no `src.jar` in there. Why is this so hard on a Mac?

Comment: This is not the case, at least with "Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 17". If I update that from http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1573, I the `Home` directory does not include any `src.jar`.

Answer (score 43):

As I understand it, as of "Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 3", there are 3 places you will find Java installed on MacOS.

- /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/ was the old place.
- /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ is the new standard place - there you will find the new release.
- /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines is for '...developer previews, and 3rd party JVMs'

Note the MacOS rule of putting Apple-supplied standard components in /System/Library and local extensions into /Library

The JDK installed by default does not now have a src.jar (although it is a JDK, so has javac etc). But if you install the 'Java Developer package' [from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action), you will get

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_22-b04-307.jdk`

which has src.jar under Contents/Home

So I think that the sane thing to do is install the developer package and point to it from your IDE.

---

Update - for "Java for Mac OS X 10.7 Update 1", having installed the developer package the source can be found at

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_29-b11-402.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar`

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Java/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate3LeopardUpdate8RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010380-CH4-SW1

Comment: This should be the answer to this question, particularly the link "from Apple" pointing to: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#

Answer (score 7):

This is my experience with src.jar !.

- As mentioned earlier, you will have to sign up for the Apple
  developer account.(its free)
- go to [Downloads for Apple developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) and then search for java.
- I have chosen "Java for OS X 2013-005 Developer Package"
- Once you download and install the package, you will find src.jar at
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_65-b14-462.jdk/Contents/Home/

  Hope this helps!

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that this is the way to go. The pic is outdated though, but process and paths are correct.

Answer (score 4):

It appears in the latest OSX 10.6.7 (java 1.6.0_24) they have cleaned up all those directories... no src.jar exists anywhere and most of the indicated directories are missing.

annoying to no end...

Comment: I think I found it in: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/**

I think I had to go through the update process to get it to show up though.

Answer (score 3):

as of today, 6/1/12, the Java Devloper Package for OSX 10.7, no longer come with src.jar under Home directory. Some google results pointing to Apple's decision in 2010 to deprecate Java support in OSX (the ported one by Apple). And Oracle start providing Mac OS X JDK since this April. So going forward, install JDK from Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

With Oracle Java SE 7 for Mac OS X x64 the src.zip ends up in the following location, in this case the particular version is Java SE 7u10

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_10.jdk/Contents/Home/src.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OS X 10.5.8, after updating to Java 1.6.0_22 and installing the most recent developer update dated 20-Oct-2010, `src.jar` for Java 6 is not present.

```
$ find /System/Library/Java /System/Library/Frameworks -name src.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.4.2/Home/src.jar
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0/Home/src.jar
```

Navigating to source in NetBeans 6.9.1 says `compiled code` for all constructors and  methods, e.g. `java.awt.Point`:

```
public Point() {
    //compiled code
    throw new RuntimeException("Compiled Code");
}
```

It may be possible to extract a usable JAR from a previous update, as suggested in this [thread](http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2008/sep/msg00360.html).

Addendum: On NetBeans, the default platform's location is an attribute in the file `~/.netbeans/6.9/config/Services/Platforms/org-netbeans-api-java-Platform/default_platform.xml`:

```
<sources>
    <resource>jar:file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
        1.6.0_22-b04-307.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar!/src/
    </resource>
</sources>
```

Alternatively, the file `/Library/Java/Home/src.jar` may be referenced:

```
<sources>
    <resource>jar:file:/Library/Java/Home/src.jar!/src/</resource>
</sources>
```

Answer (score 2):

Call me old fashioned, but:

find /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/ -name src.jar

worked for me :-)

Comment: Or better yet find /Library/Java -name "src.*"

Since it may be a .zip (was in my case)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this explains it: ?

> As of the release of Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 3, the Java runtime ported by Apple and that ships with Mac OS X is deprecated. Developers should not rely on the Apple-supplied Java runtime being present in future versions of Mac OS X [Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 3 and 10.5 Update 8 Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Java/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate3LeopardUpdate8RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want Eclipse to always point to the current default JDK and its sources point it to:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home
```

Eclipse will then resolve the symbolic link CurrentJDK and point it to the current JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to folks that have previously provided answers; they've been helpful.

As a newb to Mac (10.6.6), here's what I did for MyEclipse, which should also work for Eclipse; I've not tested this in a disconnected mode. When trying to add another JRE for MyEclipse 8.5, it required a "MacOS X VM", and would not support a "Standard VM".  I tried modifying both the eclipse.ini and myeclipse.ini files, and also tried starting MyEclipse from the command line with a specific JAVA_HOME set with no avail.

1) download and install the correct Java Developer Package. Go to System Preferences -> Software Update -> Installed Software.  You may have multiple versions of a given installation, in my case, I had both "Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 2" and "Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 3" - so be sure to sort by name, or verify some other way.  As of today, the downloaded file name was javadeveloper_10.6_10m3261.dmg.

2) In a terminal window, I added some symlinks from the OS VM that point to jars in the Standard VM.  I have slightly modified security permissions, so you may or may not need to use sudo to create the symlinks.

```
cd /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_22-b04-307.jdk/Contents/Home/appledocs.jar
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_22-b04-307.jdk/Contents/Home/docs.jar
sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_22-b04-307.jdk/Contents/Home/src.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

if nothing is working just download the sources from http://jdk7src.sourceforge.net/ here and add them. worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the src.zip on my mac at
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachine/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/src.zip

Adding to 'project structure - SDKs - Sourcepath' allowed me to view java source files in IntelliJ...