# Netbeans and Javadoc

Tags: java, netbeans

You awesome people may know how to do this.

I know that once I download the correct file I can import the file by clicking Tools > Library > and select Javadoc > then selecting add zip/folder.

I am running the following.

Product Version: NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 (Build 201007282301)
Java: 1.6.0_22; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server
System: Mac OS X version 10.6.5

*** All I believe I need is the correct link to the correct Javadoc zip file and I can do the rest. I have tried looking but am literally confused between all the options Oracle offers.

Comment: So.. what are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html, scroll down until you see *Java SE 6 Documentation* and click the *Download Zip* button

Comment: Thanks yock, and trashgod. You guys are really great! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Once you get the relevant API documentation, as suggested by @yock, you'll want to edit `Tools > Java Platforms > Javadoc`, rather than `Tools > Libraries > Javadoc`. On a related note, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011670) has more details on locating `src.zip`.